# Recurrence Rule +vCalendar

Tags: calendar, rules, recurrence

Recurrence Rule:
This property is identified by the property name RRULE. This property defines a rule or repeating pattern for a recurring vCalendar entity, based on the Basic Recurrence Rule Grammar of XAPIA's CSA. The value for the property is a pattern specification for the recurrence. The following is an example of this property:

```
RRULE:W2 TU TH          // Every other week, on Tuesday and Thursday
RRULE:D1 #10                // Daily for 10 occurrences
RRULE:YM1 6 7 #8            // Yearly in June and July for 8 occurrences
Support for this property is optional for implementations conforming to this specification.
```

so for this "Recurrence Rule" is their any algorithm so that it is easy to develop it.

Comment: The iCal spec is [RFC 5545](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545) (from RFC 2445).  One common implementation for that is [google-rfc-2445](https://web.archive.org/web/20151118134746/https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/), but since Google Code was shut down, there's no obvious successor. Maybe try [jcvanderwal's clone](https://github.com/jcvanderwal/google-rfc-2445).

Answer (score 2):

To me algorithm is what you have mentioned here .. i.e. "RRULE" .. you can "reverse-engineer" it to develop an application/module to output it back .. so its on to you (i.e. developer) to how to get output in this format.

I know that its not an easy job as I have played with around for a time before I came up with somewhat near solution. You can try some basic scheduler by creating a table, say events, with some of the fields like recurrence_type (daily, monthly, weekly, monthly_by_day, monthly_by_date), repeat_until, num_occurences etc.

To have all of the combinations of the RRULES it has to be very complex in order to output the desired format. I had tried it in PHP/MySQL.

Comment: sorry mate .. it was part of an application and code is not public .. you can try looking at some open source calendar applications to go through.

Comment: dude i dont need your code i need the algorithm(way to read the rrule).